# Is the "open doors" policy for a project manager always beneficial?

Tags: management, projects, efficiency, project-management

I've heard that the "open doors" policy is beneficial, as it lets anyone come to the project manager with any problem that might arise. At the same time being interrupted at irregular times can be detrimental to productivity, as it takes everyone some time before they get back into the optimal mindset for work.

This is why I'm wondering if it is always beneficial for a project manager to implement an "open doors" policy?

Comment: This is a hugely broad question for a site like this. Don't you think it would be better to ask about a specific problem you are encountering so the folks here can provide very specific advice about how to overcome it? As asked, you are just inviting a bunch of platitudes that aren't really going to solve anyone's problems.

Comment: Open door policy is not really so much about "Enter the door anytime without permission". *Open Door policy* is essentially mean that even juniors can approach anyone up above (to some extent) and discuss issues freely. This helps sometimes in to reduce anxieties of these folks or provide updates on critical issues to management which are otherwise getting shelved within the hierarchy.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

All management is essentially about managing people and the "Open Door" policy is one of most useful tools in the arsenal.

There may be times when you are engrossed in something and don't want to be interrupted, in those cases, it's perfectly ok to just let it be known either via a sign or instructions. The person will understand and come back at a better time unless it's really urgent.

At the end of the day, having an "open door" is more of an attitude then a process. If they use it, it means they trust that you care. If they know you are sincere when you say you have an open door, a "busy, come back in 30 mins unless urgent" sign doesn't change the effectiveness of the policy and you can still have small private moments if necessary.

Answer (score 7):

One of the primary responsibilities of a project manager is to help clear roadblocks and facilitate communications between stakeholders.  The last thing a project manager would want would be to not hear about a problem that needs attention until the weekly status meeting, for example.